# Differences between stock Apache on OS X 10.5 Leopard and OS X 10.5 Leopard Server?

Tags: apache, macos, osx-leopard

Would someone with first-hand experience be able to tell me if there are any differences between the Apache installation that comes with OS X 10.5 Leopard and OS X 10.5 Leopard Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS X Server Leopard version has support for extra modules such as the Wiki and Blog server, mod_jk, spotlight searching, and few more integration few features.

You also get a nice GUI to administrate your websites and features.

Comment: Noted. Although I'm not a fan of the GUI, as I'm accustomed to tweaking .conf files from years of *NIX administration.

Comment: Abie: if you are more comfortable hand editing the config files, you may be better off doing Mac Ports based Apache2 (+ whatever parts you need) install. I find I get updates much faster via Mac Ports than from Apple. And my configs are not changed by OS X updates.